# Using a 50mA switch on a 2 amp load

Tags: power, switches, 12v

Let me preface by saying I'm a total noob at all of this and just learning as I go via the internet.

I'm working on a home project where I need to trigger a submersible pump. I needed the switch for this pump to be as small as possible so I decided to use a tactile switch. The power supply I'm using is a 12V DC battery. The contact rating for the switch is 50mA @ 12Vdc. The power consumption of the pump is 2 amps.

Based on my limited knowledge it sounds like if I use this switch to turn on the pump it will burn out the switch. Am I correct? Is there something I can put in between the load and the switch to allow me to still use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will burn out the switch.

The thing that you can put between the switch and the pump is a relay. Choose a relay with a coil current below 50mA, and with contacts suitable for your pump current.

Comment: To clarify, the coil current can be at-or-below 50mA? Or simply just below 50mA?

Comment: @afterinfinity:  It is good practice to operate almost anything at less than its maximum rating.  If the maximum current rating of the switch is 50 mA, you should not ask it to carry more than 50  mA.